# Django Admin model editor: grey out field if another boolean field is not checked

Tags: django, django-admin

I have the following two fields in my `Treatment` Model:

```
is_followup = models.BooleanField()
parent_treatment = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True,
                                     on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

In the screen grab below from my admin page, I'd like to grey out "Parent treatment" if is followup is not checked. **Is this possible? and if so, how to do it?**

[image: Screenshot Django-admin page]

Answer (score 0):

You have to do that in JavaScript.

This code snippet may help you:

```
django.jQuery(function($) {
    'use strict';

    var $isFollowup = $('#id_is_followup');
    
    function toggleCheckbox() {
        $('#id_parent_treatment').prop('disabled', !$isFollowup.prop('checked'));
    }

    $isFollowup.on('change', toggleCheckbox);
    toggleCheckbox();
});
```

Don't forget to refer to this JavaScript snippet from your Model-Admin, using:

```
class TreatmentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    Media:
        js = ['my-project/treatment-admin.js']
```